# Not displaying history table in cs50 finance solution

Tags: python, html, web, finance, stock

I am currently head-butting with the finance solution of cs50.

It seems I have managed to succeed with everything besides the history table, as when clicking on the history link nothing is displayed but I am also not receiving any error messages...

This is my history code in the application.py:

```
@app.route("/history")
@login_required
def history():
    rows = db.execute("SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE user_id = :user",
                          user=session["user_id"])
    transactions = []
    for row in rows:
        stock_info = lookup(row['symbol'])
        if row['isbought'] == '0':
            row['value'] = "-" & row['value']

        transactions.append(list((stock_info['symbol'], stock_info['name'], row['shares'], usd(row['value']), row['transacted'])))

    return render_template("history.html", transactions=transactions)
```

and this is my history.html:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    History
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <th>SYMBOL</th>
            <th>NAMES</th>
            <th>SHARES</th>
            <th>VALUE</th>
            <th>DATE</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for transaction in transactions %}
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">{{ transaction[0] }}</th>
                <td>{{ transaction[1] }}</td>
                <td>{{ transaction[2] }}</td>
                <td>{{ transaction[3] }}</td>
                <td>{{ transaction[4] }}</td>
              </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>

    </table>
{% endblock %}
```

If you need to see the rest of my code, then please comment below. I would greatly appreciate any help with debugging my work!

Comment: why are you using & in ````row['value'] = "-" & row['value']````

Comment: before `return render_template...` add `print(len(transactions ))` and you will see how many lines you should get in the table.

Comment: @Advay168 I want to display the price of the transaction as a negative value as it is being sold. How would you recommend to do this?

Comment: is ````row['value']```` a string or integer? If it is a string write ````row['value'] = "-"+ row['value']```` otherwise ````row['value'] = - row['value']````